# Rsync: dealing with absolute symlinks

Tags: rsync, synchronization, symbolic-link, symlink

Having read through the rsync manpage, I can't see any way for rsync to automagically transform absolute symlinks between machines, i.e

```
Server A
file -> /home/username/path/file

Server B
file -> /home/differentusername/path/file
```

Any ideas (bearing in mind that the rsync would only be run under /home/username/)?

Comment: I assume using relative symlinks is not an option?

Comment: I'll put it this way, I'd ideally like to do it without :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Would this information lead to a solution?

From `man rsync`:

> . . .
>
> If you
>                 want to duplicate a server-side symlink, include both  the  symlink via its path, and referent directory via its real path.
>
> . . .
>
> It is also possible to limit the amount of path information that
>                 is sent as implied directories for each path you specify.   With
>                 a  modern  rsync on the sending side (beginning with 2.6.7), you
>                 can insert a dot and a slash into the source path, like this:
>
> rsync -avR /foo/./bar/baz.c remote:/tmp/
>
> That would create /tmp/bar/baz.c on the remote  machine.   (Note
>                 that  the dot must be followed by a slash, so “/foo/.” would not
>                 be abbreviated.)
>
> . . .

[omitted some information regarding earlier versions of `rsync`]