# rsync to adapt links that have absolute paths to the location at destination

Tags: rsync, symlink

Would it be possible with rsync to adapt the absolute, symbolic links to a new location at the destination?

**Test case** 
Imagine I have a link pointing to a file like this:

> /usera/files/common/test_file 
>   /usera/files/common/links/test_link -> /usera/files/common/test_file

Now I would like to rsync the whole directory `common` to another location. (group permissions are adapted, look below why)

> rsync -av --no-g /usera/files/common/ /userb/common

That gives me:

> /userb/common/test_file 
>   /userb/common/links/test_link -> /usera/files/common/test_file

**The problem** 
The problem is that the group on the destination is different than on the source (security reasons), so that the `test_link` does not point to `/userb/` space but rather to `/usera/` and therefore is not readable for this user.

**Question**
Would it be possible to tell rsync to adapt the links below the syncing point (`/common/` here) to fit to the new destination? That would give a link as such:

> /userb/common/links/test_link -> /userb/common/test_file

I tried following the solution to a [similar problem](https://serverfault.com/questions/163931/rsync-dealing-with-absolute-symlinks), however it does not seem to do what I want..

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rsync does not support that. It could be modified to do so but rsync already has too many options. You could accomplish your goal by executing this after the rsync:

```
find /tmp/userb -type l -ls |
awk '$13 ~ /^\/tmp\/usera/ { sub("/tmp/usera/files/", "/tmp/userb/", $13); print $11, $13 }' |
while read A B; do rm $A; ln -s $B $A; done
```

Comment: Thanks a lot.That's a pity, though I do understand that rsync is overloaded. I will try your solution.

Answer (score 0):

Also allowing spaces in either filename (thus using "?" as separator, which at least is a forbidden character in NTFS filesystems):

```
find /tmp/userb -type l -printf "%p?%l\n" |
awk -vFS="?" '$2 ~ /^\/tmp\/usera/ { sub("/tmp/usera/files/", "/tmp/userb/", $2); print $1 "?" $2 }' |
while IFS=? read A B; do rm "$A"; ln -s "$B" "$A"; done
```